# how to show the calendar when click on the UIButton

Tags: objective-c

I've found a few questions about how to show the calendar when click the button and select a date, then the calendar is hide.

Comment: Hi Sachin, Welcome to SO. Please take a look at our http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask guide. It is unclear as to what exactly you are looking for, also what have you tried etc.

Answer (score 0):

use this library https://github.com/jaykz52/CKCalendar

and set segue popover on button click/